# How to keep a docker container run for ever

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I created a Dockerfile which sets up python environment so that when people run the image in their host, they can run my python file without installing multiple python packages themselves.

The problem is after I build and run the image, the container stopped immediately (because it completed).

How can I keep the container running forever? My understanding is after people pull and run my image, they can start to run python file by running "python file.python".

my Dockerfile looks like this (may not be correct. I am still learning):

```
FROM python:3-alpine
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install configparser
```

Comment: After your program has exited, what's the container supposed to do?  Why don't you want it to exit?  (You also might look at the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org), there are standard ways to package Python applications that don't require root access or other Docker trickinesses to run.)

Comment: Thanks David, I want to run the container so that people can start to execute their pyhton file without installing different python packages themselves. so this container should run for ever for them to do that. if the container exit, then how can they execute the python (and other packages)?

Comment: `docker run yourimage` runs the `test_python.py` script, and when that script exits, the container exits.  You can run that `docker run` command as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks David. so every time when people run their file they need to run "docker run XXX?" I thought they run "docker run XXX" then they can start to use "python their_file.py".

Comment: Thanks David, then what if different people have different python files they need to run? like A want to run "python test_pythonA.py" using the container, B want to run "python test_pythonB.py" using the container?

Comment: They...need Python.  There's not really any way around that.  If you're just trying to encapsulate a set of Python dependencies, `pip install -r requirements.txt` is a pretty well-established way to install those into a virtual environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze: python is my start point, I am going to install other un-python package later on. my plan is to have a container which has python, configparser, psycopg2 pandas, awscli, boto3, psycopg2, etc. and then they just run my container and then execute their python files.

Comment: @DavidMaze in fact the Dockerfile does not need to have the last line CMD ["python", "test_python.py"] so I have remove it. people need to run their python files not test_python.py. in this case, how does people run the container with they files?

Comment: Looks you are trying to use docker as a normal virtual machine. In your case, when the container starts running, every time you need to transfer your target script into container and type related command to run like `python xx.py`, which is not a typical usage situation of docker I think.

Comment: [How to keep docker containers running](http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/)

Comment: @Lebecca: Thanks. I create a docker so people does not need to install packages in their devices in order to run my python file. isn't docker a good solution for this case? -d is not useful for my Dockerfile because the container does complete immediately.

Comment: No, docker is used for publishing a specific application, packaging one of your specific python script is ok and people will get this script ran with dockerfile properly set. But it seems like you want to run docker as a machine, and people are free to run whatever they want.

Comment: @Lebecca, Thanks I added CMD tail -f /dev/null at the end of Dockerfile so it does not stop, but when I run "python test_python.py" the python command still is not recognized, look like test_python.py is not within the environment of the container that is runing. there are must someway to link test_python.py with the container.

Comment: Haha, I truly think you are doing something out the scope of docker (maybe kind of hack docker too). Docker are designed to deploy application on multi-platform, the xx.py should be placed to container in docker build step and always run in that container, and this make the running of your application environment-independent. You may read some docs to know the intention of docker more deeply.

Comment: @Lebecca yeah I feel I misunderstood how I should use docker. from what I learned here now is : docker is to run an application not to setup an environment. in fact, I guess what I should do is to pass the file to the above dockerfile using argument and I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, that's it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [HOW TO KEEP DOCKER CONTAINERS RUNNING](http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/07/how-to-keep-docker-containers-running/), we can know that docker containers, when run in detached mode (the most common -d option), are designed to shut down immediately after the initial entrypoint command (program that should be run when container is built from image) is no longer running in the foreground. So to keep docker container run even the inside program has done

- just add `CMD tail -f /dev/null` as last line to dockerfile

What's more important is that we should understand what's docker is intended for and how to use it properly. Try to use docker as environment foundation for applications in host machine is not a good choice, docker is designed to run applications environment-independent. Applications should be placed into docker image via docker build and run in docker container in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you run your image.. You can do command below so it is interactive and you can execute more commands inside the contaner after it has run

```
docker run -it <your-image> bash
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Dockerfile is lacking a CMD. It doesn't do anything right now.

You need to append the following;

```
## Run the script
CMD [ "python", "-u", "./your-script.py"]
```

I'm adding -u so Python runs in unbuffered output mode. If you don't, you probably won't see output from your script.

If you now start your container attached, you can view it's output

```
docker run your-container
```

You can also run it detached, and attach later.

```
docker run -d --name container-name your-container
```

Naming your container makes it significantly easier to manage it's lifetime.

Attach to your output using either

```
docker logs container-name
```

Or with interaction using

```
docker attach container-name
```